# Image as background of svg path

Tags: html, svg

I am having problem dealing with an svg path with an image as a background. Somehow no matter what I do the image is not filling up the path. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```html
<svg
    width="300"
    height="300"
    viewBox="200 110 160 320"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
    <defs>
        <pattern id="profile" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="400">
            <image xlinkHref="img.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g transform='translate(300,300)'>
        <path d="M102.1,-53.2C114.1,3.9,93.2,51.7,58.4,76C23.5,100.3,-25.3,101.1,-72.4,73.2C-119.4,45.2,-164.8,-11.5,-152.5,-69C-140.1,-126.5,-70.1,-184.8,-12.5,-180.7C45,-176.6,90,-110.3,102.1,-53.2Z" fill="url(#profile)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you see the image at all? If not, I recommend trying replacing `xlinkHref` with `xlink:href`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Clip an image in a certain shape?

Comment: xlinkHref is because I am using react. I am trying to display an image as a background of an svg path. Right now the image looks like this: https://ibb.co/y8WtWFg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a pattern to fill the image you can use the path to clip the image like so:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="200 110 160 320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="cp">
    <path transform='translate(300,300)' d="M102.1,-53.2C114.1,3.9,93.2,51.7,58.4,76C23.5,100.3,-25.3,101.1,-72.4,73.2C-119.4,45.2,-164.8,-11.5,-152.5,-69C-140.1,-126.5,-70.1,-184.8,-12.5,-180.7C45,-176.6,90,-110.3,102.1,-53.2Z" />
  </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" clip-path="url(#cp)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you a lot!